# Multiple End events in one Process

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management

Can I use multiple End event in One Process?
if yes, How to declare which End Event is Main End Event?
To Clarify the Question, let me  demonstrate it.
We have main process that has a sub process. There is a inclusive or parallel gateway inside sub process that branch out into multiple paths. All of the paths leads to None End event. 
Which End event is triggered in order to continue main process?
for example in attached image [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b06uk.png) , I want Main Process to be continued and run Task1, whenever  End Event B be triggered (None of the both other End events, A or C)

Comment: I have just created a proposal for a new community that only deals with business process modeling because I noticed that many business-related questions around process modeling are lost amongst the software-focussed questions around modeling apps in the stackexchange community. Feel free to have a look and I am looking forward to your inputs regarding the community's future ! : https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121238/business-process-modeling?referrer=IU7kc0WmXuuHw8-vDBM9aw2

Answer (score 0):

I would add an exlusive gateway after your subprocess that is asking the question "What was the result of the subprocess?". But I think you could also simplify the model:

Since the activities related to A and C are always executed but have no significance for the rest of the process, I would do them separattely from B and then check if B was the case or not. This basically translates to "We have to do A and C but we really only care about B".

Here are both versions as I would have done them.

[image]